# Not receiving any sandbox notifications for eBay

Tags: ebay-api

Using the below code, I am not seeing any sandbox notifications to our url or email for any event. I tried posting on eBay's dev forums but it seems to be a tumbleweed blowing through the planes over there.

I ran both sets of code to setup the notifications and then added a item, set feedback on it, marked it as sold. Nothing causes a notification.

This is the code for the application settings.

```
SetNotificationPreferencesCall apiCall = new SetNotificationPreferencesCall(usrApiContext);
var appPref = new ApplicationDeliveryPreferencesType();
appPref.ApplicationEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable;
appPref.ApplicationURL = "http://[ourdomain]/eBay/notification/receive";
appPref.AlertEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable;
appPref.AlertEmail = "mailto:jxxx@ourdomain.com";
appPref.PayloadVersion = "989";
appPref.DeviceType = DeviceTypeCodeType.Platform;
appPref.NotificationPayloadType = NotificationPayloadTypeCodeType.eBLSchemaSOAP;
apiCall.SetNotificationPreferences(appPref);
```

This is the code for the user.

```
var usrPref = new NotificationEnableTypeCollection();
#region Setup Notifications
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.AskSellerQuestion });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.AuctionCheckoutComplete });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.BestOffer });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.BestOfferDeclined });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.BestOfferPlaced });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.BidItemEndingSoon });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.BidPlaced });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.BidReceived });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.BulkDataExchangeJobCompleted });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.BuyerCancelRequested });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.BuyerResponseDispute });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.Checkout });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.CheckoutBuyerRequestsTotal });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.CounterOfferReceived });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.EndOfAuction });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.Feedback });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.FeedbackForSeller });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.FeedbackLeft });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.FeedbackReceived });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.FeedbackStarChanged });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.FixedPriceTransaction });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemAddedToBidGroup });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemAddedToWatchList });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemClosed });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemExtended });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemListed });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemLost });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemMarkedPaid });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemMarkedShipped });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemRevised });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemRevisedAddCharity });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemsCanceled });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemSold });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemSuspended });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemUnsold });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ItemWon });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.M2MMessageStatusChange });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.MyMessageseBayMessage });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.OutBid });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.PaymentReminder });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.PlaceOffer });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReadyForPayout });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReadyToShip });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.RefundFailure });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.RefundSuccess });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.RemoveFromWatchList });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReturnClosed });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReturnCreated });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReturnDelivered });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReturnEscalated });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReturnRefundOverdue });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReturnSellerInfoOverdue });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReturnShipped });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ReturnWaitingForSellerInfo });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.SecondChanceOffer });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.SellerClosedDispute });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.SellerOpenedDispute });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.SellerRespondedToDispute });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.ShoppingCartItemEndingSoon });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.TokenRevocation });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.UnmatchedPaymentReceived });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.UserIDChanged });
usrPref.Add(new NotificationEnableType() { EventEnable = EnableCodeType.Enable, EventType = NotificationEventTypeCodeType.WatchedItemEndingSoon });
#endregion
apiCall.SetNotificationPreferences(usrPref);
```

Comment: Do you have any Updates?  I am not receiving any notifications on Sandbox either.

Comment: FYI - I made a call to production with the the same code I was using on Sandbox and it worked, so there must be issues with Sandbox(even though they say it is supposed to work).

Comment: Well that really sucks now doesn't it...  How are we to test something if the test env doesn't work, and the production env costs you money to test in...

Comment: I can't even get notifications to work in production, let alone in the sandbox. And the eBay developer forum is garbage.